# How to add product to cart by quantity? - Context API - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management, react-state-management, react-context

I have been able to get the functionality of my state management to the point where I can add to the basket and remove the item from the basket, however I want to be able to check if item is already in the basket and if so just update the quantity and also remove by quantity rather than the basketItem removing entirely even if there was more than one of it.

If you look at the basket when adding items it just adds more basket items with each of them displaying total quantity - but I just want the quantity to update in the basketItem when there is more than one.

- for reference I have not yet implemented the CHANGE_CART_QUANTITY reducer as I am having difficulty working out how to use it in my application

code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/10a9ee0b400)

code below:
CartContext.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import { CartReducer } from "./CartReducer";
import { products } from "../../pages/ProductDetailsPage";

const Cart = createContext();


const Context = ({ children }) => {
 

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(CartReducer, {
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });

//   const [productState, productDispatch] = useReducer(productReducer, {
//     byStock: false,
//     byFastDelivery: false,
//     byRating: 0,
//     searchQuery: "",
//   });

//   console.log(productState);

  return (
    <Cart.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
      {children}
    </Cart.Provider>
  );
};

export const CartState = () => {
  return useContext(Cart);
};

export default Context;
```

CartReducer.js

```
import {ADD_TO_CART, CHANGE_CART_QUANTITY, REMOVE_FROM_CART} from '../Types'

export const CartReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TO_CART: {
            return {
                ...state, 
                cart: [...state.cart, { ...action.payload, qty : 1}]
            };
        }
        case REMOVE_FROM_CART: {
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter((c) => c.id !== action.payload.id),
            };
        }
        case CHANGE_CART_QUANTITY:
            return {
                ...state,
                cart: state.cart.filter(c => c.id === action.payload.id ? c.qty = action.payload.qty : c.qty )
            }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

Product.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'

import { QuantityButtonDiv } from './QuantityButtonDiv'
import {BasketItem} from './BasketItem'
import { CartContext, CartState } from '../context/cart/CartContext'
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../context/Types'

export const Product = ({product}) => {

    // const {addToCart, cartItems, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext)
    const { state: {cart}, dispatch } = CartState();
   

    return (
        <div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={product.image}/>
            </div>
            <div className="details-div">
                <h1>{product.title}</h1>
                <span>
                    {product.description}
                </span>
                <span className="price">
                    £ {product.price}
                </span>
                <div className="stock-div">
                    {product.stock} in stock
                </div>
                <QuantityButtonDiv/>
                {cart.some((p) => p.id === product.id) ? (
                    //checking to see if item is in cart if so remove from cart button appears
                    <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                        type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
                        payload: product,
                    })}  className="remove-button">
                        Remove From Cart
                    </button>

                ) : (
                    <></>
                )}
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                    type: ADD_TO_CART,
                    payload: product,
                })} disable={!product.stock}  className="add-to-cart-button">
                    {!product.stock ? "Out Of Stock" : "Add To Cart"}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

BasketItem.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import image from '../assets/image.png'
// import { QuantityButtonDiv } from '../components/QuantityButtonDiv'
import plusButtonImage from '../assets/vector+.png'
import subtractButtonImage from '../assets/vector.png'
import { CartState } from '../context/cart/CartContext'
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from '../context/Types'
import CustomizedSelect from './SelectInput'


export const BasketItem = ({item}) => {

    // const { cartItems, removeItem } = useContext(CartContext);
    const { 
        state: { cart },
        dispatch,
    } = CartState();

    return (
        <div className="basket-item">
            <div className="title-div">
                <span>
                    {item.title}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="image-div">
                <img style={{height: "100%", width: "100%"}} src={image}/>
            </div>
            <div className="price-div">
                <span>
                    £{item.price}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div className="basket-quantity-div">
                <button onClick={() => dispatch({
                        type: REMOVE_FROM_CART,
                        payload: item,
                    })}  className="subtract-btn">
                    <img src={subtractButtonImage}/>
                </button>
                <span className="quantity-value">
                    {cart.length}
                </span>
                <button  onClick={() => dispatch({
                    type: ADD_TO_CART,
                    payload: item,
                })} className="add-btn">
                    <img src={plusButtonImage}/>
                </button>
            </div>  
            <div className="total-div">
                £{cart.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0)}
            </div>
        </div>

    )
}
```

Comment: what is `CartState`? this piece is very suspicious, also i checked the source code, it's empty?

Comment: Sorry ignore CartState that was taken out and put in CartContext and I am just using that file - forgot to delete that after last refactor.

Comment: It seems like `payload` needs to include an item count along with the item.

Comment: @Ouroborus Thanks, Thats what I want to implement but how? when i've tried to use .quantity before it does not work and throws errors of quantity being undefined

Comment: Isn't it `.qty` rather than `.quantity`?